# AutoFac Register confusion

Tags: dependency-injection, autofac

Hi I am just been looking at AutoFac and following their getting-started tutorial

http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/index.html

having followed it and understanding how their services work I wanted to try to create a new implementation on the same interface type

```
builder.RegisterType<TodayWriter>().As<IDateWriter>();
builder.RegisterType<TomorrowWriter>().As<IDateWriter>();
```

Both implentations contain the same code

```
public class TomorrowWriter : IDateWriter
{
    private IOutput _output;

    public TomorrowWriter(IOutput output)
    {
        this._output = output;
    }

    public void WriteDate()
    {
        this._output.Write(DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).ToShortDateString());
    }
}
```

So TodaysWriter is the same apart from the WriteDate method displaying

```
this._output.Write(DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString());
```

instead.

So now using the application, how do I determine what implementation to use as both methods are called WriteDate()

```
        using(var scope = Container.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {
            var writer = scope.Resolve<IDateWriter>();

            // Is this using todaysWriter or TomorrowWriter?
            writer.WriteDate();
        }
```

Am I using this wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To differentiate between different implementations of the same interface look at [named and keyed services](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html) in the docs.

Alternatively you can roll your own by registering a `DateWriterFactory` and having a method on that to get a specific `IDateWriter` implementation.  something like:

```
public class DateWriterFactory
{
    IDateWriter GetWriter(string writerName)
    {
        if (writername=="TodayWriter")
            return new TodayWriter();
        if (writername=="TomorrowWriter")
            return new TomorrowWriter();
    }
}
```

obviously the implementation of the factory could be as complex or as simple as you need. Or you could just have methods to get the fixed writers rather than pass in a string.

Comment: Thank you, Just wanted to make sure my understanding was clear, if other sections touch on what I asked, I am happy.